# How do I change the order of repositories in Xcode 4 Organizer's Repositories list? or the initially selected repository?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode4.3

I'm trying to change the order of the repositories listed in Xcode 4 Organizer's Repositories. Whenever I open this window it selects the first repository in the list. I have several repositories that I'm working with, and my current project isn't first in the list. I'd like to be able to move my current project to the top, without having to delete other repositories (and then have to add them back later).

As an alternative, is there a way to make a specific repository the one that Xcode selects when you open Organizer's Repositories view, instead of the first in the list?

I have tried selecting and dragging the repository to the top, but that only changes the currently selected repository. I have tried control-clicking the repository but only get the 'Repositories Organizer Help' menu.

The 'Repositories Organizer Help' doesn't offer any suggestions. I've looked in Xcode's Preferences but there isn't anything there that can make this change. I've searched [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) for answers, but I have not found a match. I've also searched [Google](https://www.google.com/), again with no success.

Recommendations? Suggestions? Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer:  you can't.  Lame.

Long answer:  Some may regard this as "a bug", while others may just agree that is "inconsistent"…  Either way.. if you can't easily find a solution to an undesirable aspect of Xcode's functionality, the BEST thing to do is [to file a bug report with Apple](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/).

Another, slightly dicier, though possibly more fruitful plan of action may be to [check out the Xcode-4-Fixins project on Github](https://github.com/armadillu/Xcode-4-Fixins).  A LOT of my grievances with the IDE have been melted away by the fine work of those developers… Maybe a nicely-phrased request could also sway them to take on this minor UI quirk?